# null pointer exception java accessing nested json object using maven group org.json

Tags: java, maven, json

this is my depedency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
```

this is my json object

```
{
   "authorize": {
       "balance": "9984.06",
       "country": "id",
       "currency": "USD",
       "email": "xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com",
       "fullname": "  ",
       "is_virtual": 1,
       "landing_company_fullname": "Binary Ltd",
       "landing_company_name": "virtual",
       "loginid": "VRg4423",
       "scopes": [
         "read",
         "trade"
       ]
   }
}
```

this is my code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(fil);
JSONObject jsonChildObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("authorize");
Iterator iterator  = jsonChildObject.keys();
String key = null;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    key = (String) iterator.next();
    System.out.println("balance value:" + ((JSONObject) jsonChildObject.get(key)).get("balance"));
}
```

I have no idea why I can't acces all the child node value. It returns null pointer exception there is no "authorize" i can't get the parent value.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace

Comment: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["authorize"] not found.
 at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:471)
 at com.belgedezbot.coba.main(coba.java:32)

Comment: sure this is the stack trace

Comment: So it's not a NullPointerException, actually? Post that in the question. And we have no idea what `fil`is. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. My advice: use your debugger. Or at least print the contents of your variables to know what's going on.

Comment: fil is variable file reader for the json file FileReader fil = new FileReader

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at your code and we'll find the problem:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(fil);
 // jsonObject is now your whole json
 // {
 //    "authorize": 
 //     ...
 // }

JSONObject jsonChildObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("authorize");
 // the "authorize" child node is now contained in jsonChildObject
 // {
 //    "balance": "9984.06",
 //    "country": "id",
 //    "currency": "USD",
 //     ...
 // }

Iterator iterator  = jsonChildObject.keys();
// jsonChildObject.keys() iterates over this set:
// ["balance", "country", "currency" ... ]

String key = null;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    key = (String) iterator.next(); 
    // the very first iteration, key will have the value "balance"

    System.out.println("balance value:" 
       + ((JSONObject) jsonChildObject.get(key)).get("balance"));
    // and here you try to get the element "balance" from the element with the key "balance"
}
```

Basically the line

```
((JSONObject) jsonChildObject.get(key)).get("balance"))
```

looks like this during the first iteration:

```
((JSONObject) jsonChildObject.get("balance")).get("balance"))
```

which of course does not exist.

**1)**  if you only want the "balance", don't iterate over the keys and remove the `while` loop. Just write `jsonChildObject.get("balance")`

**2)**  if you need to get *ALL* children and you want to keep the `while` loop, the you could do a switch over they keys:

```
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    key = (String) iterator.next();
    switch(key){
        case "balance": 
             float balance = jsonChildObject.get(key);
             break;
        case "country":
            ...
    }
```

It's either that, or some other library (like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)) that automatically maps your json in a simple POJO that you wrote before

**Maven dependency for Gson**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I would go for **1)** and simply get all your values by *manually* calling `jsonChildObject.get("balance")` or `...get("country");` and so on.

**EDIT**

I just realized you have problems getting "authorize", maybe a simple `print` would do to show you how your json looks like:

```
System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(3));  // should give you a nicely printed JSON. If this is already `null` then the problem is already in `fil` which might be the wrong json.
```

Comment: thanks, the problem is the file